# vim: How to detect stdin input in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, stdin

How can one detect stdin input in `.vimrc`?

I have the following command in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

to open a file with a cursor at the last line position. However, if I use vim on stdin, I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*":
E32: No file name
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can one detect that vim is used on stdin in `.vimrc` to suppress execution of the command in such cases?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v:argv` is a list that begins with the complete path of the program, and contains each argument, if any.

If you call Vim like this:

```
$ vim
```

`:echo v:argv` outputs something like:

```
['/path/to/vim']
```

If you call Vim like this:

```
$ vim foo.txt bar.json
```

`:echo v:argv` outputs something like:

```
['/path/to/vim', 'foo.txt', 'bar.json']
```

If you call Vim like this:

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | vim -
```

`:echo v:argv` outputs something like:

```
['/path/to/vim', '-']
```

Therefore, you can condition the execution of `:loadview` to the content of `v:argv[1]`. Note that we use `get()` because the index `1` may not exist:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * if get(v:argv, 1, '') != '-' | silent loadview | endif
```

Reference:

```
:help :get()
:help v:argv
```

Comment: This seems version-dependent, but a quick glance doesn't show what version/feature-set is required. On Vim ver 8.0.1763 (shared server environment), I do 
`:echo v:argv` and I get:
`Undefined variable: v:argv`